# Parsing CSV files using Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I'm trying to write a script that will open a CSV file and write rows from that file to a new CSV file based on the match criteria of a unique telephone number in column 4 of `csv.csv`. The phone numbers are always in column 4, and are often duplicated in the file, however the other columns are often unique, thus each row is inherently unique.

A row from the csv file I'm reading looks like this: (the TN is `9259991234`)

```
2,PPS,2015-09-17T15:44,9259991234,9DF51758-A2BD-4F65-AAA2
```

I hit an error with the code below saying that '_csv.writer' is not iterable and I'm not sure how to modify my code to solve the problem.

```
import csv
import sys
import os

os.chdir(r'C:\pTest')

with open(r'csv.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    with open (r'new_csv.csv', 'ab') as new_f:
        writer = csv.writer(new_f, delimiter=',')
        for row in reader:
            if row[3] not in writer:
                writer.writerow(new_f)
```

Comment: What do you expect `row[3] not in writer` to do? You cannot test for membership in a writer; that data is already written. If you want to track phone numbers already processed, you need to keep a separate `set()` object and test against that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error stems from this expression:

```
row[3] not in writer
```

You cannot test for membership against a `csv.writer()` object. If you wanted to track if you already have processed a phone number, use a separate `set()` object to track those:

```
with open(r'csv.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    with open (r'new_csv.csv', 'ab') as new_f:
        writer = csv.writer(new_f, delimiter=',')
        seen = set()
        for row in reader:
            if row[3] not in seen:
                seen.add(row[3])
                writer.writerow(row)
```

Note that I also changed your `writer.writerow()` call; you want to write the row, not the file object.

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you! This is quite literally my first attempt at writing anything in Python, so the feedback is much appreciated.